# List all public ips attached to compute VM'S in GCP using Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to list the public IPs attached to a VM in all projects within an organization. Below is the code I am using:

Not sure what's missing but it isn't listing the public IPs ... Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with **re.findall(...)**. Do not search data structures for data that is already well structured.

The public IP address is assigned to **networkInteraces[].accessConfigs[].natIP**.

The private IP is **networkInteraces[].networkIP**.

Below is an example of the data returned from the API:

```
  "networkInterfaces": [
    {
      "kind": "compute#networkInterface",
      "network": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/mystic-advice/global/networks/default",
      "subnetwork": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/mystic-advice/regions/us-west1/subnetworks/default",
      "networkIP": "10.138.0.2",
      "name": "nic0",
      "accessConfigs": [
        {
          "kind": "compute#accessConfig",
          "type": "ONE_TO_ONE_NAT",
          "name": "External NAT",
          "natIP": "35.197.59.99",
          "networkTier": "PREMIUM"
        }
      ],
      "fingerprint": "gue6vkiJdXA="
    }
  ],
```